# Flutter extract widget requires a return widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting a lot of widgets groups in the tree and wanted to start extracting them to their own widget.

I tried with Ctrl-Alt-W, this command does nothing and shows no error when there is a problem.

If you go to the top menu and click on refactor, extract, extract to widget the following error occurs:

```
Can only extract a widget expression or a method returning widget.
```

This is an example of the code I am trying to extract:

```
                     Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 8.0,
                                  right: 8.0,
                                  top: 8.0,
                                  bottom: 4.0),
                              child: new TextField(
                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                        const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    filled: true,
                                    hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey[800]),
                                    hintText: "Supervisor",
                                    fillColor: Colors.white70),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

How would I modify this code in the widget tree to have a return so that it can be easily extracted.

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply create a `StatelessWidget` with that code returned in its `build` method?

Comment: Thanks for your response I can do that no problem, but that defeats the purpose. What I have done since learning flutter is spent a lot of time learning all the shortcuts to make coding fast. The function is there in the menu so I am trying to find out how to make work.

Comment: @NicholasMuir did you managed to achieve that? It seems to be some bug for me.

Comment: Yes just put a return statement in front of it, refactor return new widget

Comment: You dont need extract all widgets just to make the code clean, when you should extrac them? when you need to use the same code in another class, then it makes sense, to organize only if you have time and want to make the code beautiful if you want. This is my guess. I made one vídeo 'in Portuguese only' showing how extrac button, if you want to take a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCssthwwOwo&t=7s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcut to extract Flutter widget from UI layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105154/shortcut-to-extract-flutter-widget-from-ui-layout)

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this is a bug. Everyone says that you have to highlight all of the code to extract it, and it worked with them, but for me, I've made it like this.
First I put the cursor at the specific widget.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly right. Other posts say to select the code block ( but this only works for extract method not extract widget )

Answer (score 3):

Ensure Two Steps:

1. Your Code is 'Dart Formatted' (if using AndroidStudio, else regular formatted with appropriate commas if using VSCode), and
2. Your Cursor is at the beginning of the widget code block that you want to extract as a widget. Cursor position is the only problem here. Even after selecting the entire code block, if we right click while cursor is somewhere in the middle of the code block, refactoring and widget extraction wont work.

Dont select the block, only ensure that cursor is at the first letter of the block. Then -> right click -> refactor -> extract widget and voila! It will work. Thanks. Happy Coding!