# Shortcut to extract Flutter widget from UI layout

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter, widget

If I have a complex layout that I want to simplify, what is the shortcut in Android Studio (or IntelliJ) to extract the widget out into a method?

Example:

I want to extract the three main widgets in the Stack.

```
class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/image.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.7, -0.7),
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'My text',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white70,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Text(
            'Some other text',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
              letterSpacing: 5.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I could do it by hand but I'm looking for a shortcut.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I'm updating this answer for both Android Studio and VS Code

## Android Studio

#### Method 1

Shortcut keys:

- **Windows/Linux**: Put your cursor on the widget name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to extract it as a method or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to extract it as a widget.
- **MacOS**: Put your cursor on the widget name and press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to extract it as a method or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to extract it as a widget.

You can also accomplish the same thing by right clicking the widget name and choosing **Refactor > Extract** from the context menu.

#### Method 2

You can also extract a widget into a method or new widget from the Flutter Outline menu.

1. Click **Flutter Outline** on the top left side
2. Select the widget in the outline
3. Right click and choose **Extract method...** or **Extract widget...**
4. Give it a name

[image]

## Visual Studio Code

Put your cursor on the widget name and press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on a Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on a PC. Then choose **Method** or **Widget** from the context menu.

[image]

Comment: widgets inside my column are not shown in flutter outline. Do you know why?

Comment: @Aseem, you might need to click the triangle on the left of the column to expand the subtree. Otherwise I don't know.

Comment: If flutter outline doesn't display the widget tree, you have to either: `Ctrl ` (or `⌘ command` macOS) and click any widget, or press the reload icon in the Dart Analysis. Information taken from [Flutter Outline Shows "Nothing to show" in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268180/flutter-outline-shows-nothing-to-show-in-android-studio)

Comment: I am using `Android Studio Chipmunk Patch 2` and All options are dim even after clicking Widget from the widget tree... and neither option appears from the suggestion bulb...

Answer (score 34):

To Extract particular code of Flutter in **Android studio** to `varialbe`, `constant`, `method`, or as a `Widget`.

**1. Select a code block you want to extract.**

[image]

**2. Right click -> Refactor -> Extract -> Select type of refactor you want.**

[image]

`Shortcuts` vary as per your Android studio configuration but shortcuts are  also written over the there too ease your task.

Comment: hmm. I dont have Option to extract Flutter Widget... I have installed flutter and dart plugins.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+m is for methods not widgets!

Answer (score 11):

In my case `Ctrl+Alt+W` hotkey in Android Studio didn't work. To fix it just open Keymap Settings and re-set this hotkey - Android Studio will remove conflicting shortcuts and it became work.

Comment: In my case Kotlin was overriding this keymap. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, change mine to [Alt+W], it works now.

Answer (score 5):

To fix the issue of the Kotlin shortcut overriding the "Extract New Widget" command, go to "Preferences > Keymap" and search for "Run Scratch File." Right-click and remove the Kotlin shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In [this post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ide-shortcuts-for-faster-development-2ef45c51085b) it is very well explained.

Comment: ALT ENTER in Android Studio is NOT a "Shortcut to extract Flutter widget from UI layout", which is exactly what Suragch was asking for. ALT ENTER allows to wrap and remove widgets. That's all. Besides, what that article explains is that in order to extract a Widget, the user should use the Flutter Outline tab. So actually that's not "well explained", as it doesn't even mentions a single shortcut to extract the widget.

Answer (score 2):

In the android studio, you can extract widget by class

```
Ctrl + Alt + W
```

or extract widget by method

```
Ctrl + Alt + M
```

Answer (score 1):

The New Shortcut Key to Extract Widget In Android Studio is
**Ctrl + Alt + E**

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio(Hedgehog):**

In my case <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`Alt`</kbd> + <kbd>`w`</kbd> shortcut **was overridden by another** Kotlin action.

**Step 1:** Find Actions by Shortcut.

Go to **Settings** -> **Keymap** and click the `Find Actions by Shortcut` button.

[image: Find Actions by Shortcut Button]

**Step 2:** Get associated actions.

Press <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`Alt`</kbd> + <kbd>`w`</kbd>. All actions will be displayed which is associated with this shortcut.

[image: all actions associated with the shortcut]

You can see that the shortcut is associated with another Kotlin action.

**Step 3:** Apply suitable actions.

Now you can edit, remove, or apply other actions on the listed shortcuts.

[image: apply actions on the shortcut]